# Size of RSA struct and size of public key in Openssl

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

Why if I call `RSA_size()` on an RSA object do I obtain a value less than the return value of `i2d_RSAPublicKey` (the size of the public key) called on the same RSA object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `i2d_RSAPublicKey` gives you a PKCS#1 encoded version of the key, including public exponent and DER elements.

`RSA_size()` gives you just the size in bytes of the pure modulus (which is also the size of any unencoded signature or ciphertext for that key).